# Using easyXDM on same domain

Tags: same-origin-policy, easyxdm

I am using easyXDM for cross domain iframe resizing.
Working fine.

If I want to use same exact function on my own domain I am getting;

Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function on easyXDM.js file.

Is there any workaround to still use easyXDM on same domain?

P.S: I know I can directly access same domain iframe without easyXDM but I just want to see if there is any solution before doing that while using same code.

Comment: found a solution for this?

Comment: @jay unfortunately not. Hope Creator of easyXDM will release a version that will work on both places.